# variadic templates - compile error

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

Could you help me in fixing the compile error in the following code:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename ...P>
class Mystrcat{
 public:
 Mystrcat(T t, P... p){init(t,p...);}

 ostringstream & get(){return o;}         

 private:
 ostringstream o;
 void init(){}
 void init(T t, P... p);
};

template<typename T, typename ...P>
void Mystrcat<T,P...>::init(T t, P ...p){
  o << t;
  if (sizeof...(p)) init(p...);
}

int main(){
 Mystrcat<char*,char *> m("Amma","Namasivayah");
 cout << m.get().str();
}
```

I get the error, no matching function for call to

```
‘Mystrcat<char*, char*>::init(char*&)’
```

note: candidates are:

```
void Mystrcat<T, P>::init() [with T = char*, P = char*]
void Mystrcat<T, P>::init(T, P ...) [with T = char*, P = char*]
```

gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5)

Thanks
suresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this error because there isn't a way to unpack your `p` into either `init` function.  In your instantiation `Mystrcat<char*, char *>`, unpacking a `P...` will yield a single thing in the type: `char*`, which doesn't have an `init` with that signature (the instantiated version will have a `void init()` and `void init(char*, char*)`, whereas you are trying to call `init(char*)`).

In fact, your template is impossible to instantiate, since `init` will always take one more argument than you give it in `void Mystrcat<T,P...>::init(T t, P ...p)`.  If you change the definition to call what you have defined:

```
template<typename T, typename ...P>
void Mystrcat<T,P...>::init(T t, P ...p){
  o << t;
  if (sizeof...(p)) init(t, p...);
}
```

then this will work (at least in g++-4.5.2).

---

**EDIT**: I think this is what you're actually looking for:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

class MyCollector
{
public:
    template <typename... T>
    explicit MyCollector(const T&... args)
    {
        init(args...);
    }

    std::string str()
    {
        return _stream.str();
    }

private:
    void init()
    { }

    template <typename First, typename... Rest>
    void init(const First& first, const Rest&... rest)
    {
        _stream << first;
        init(rest...);
    }

    std::ostringstream _stream;
};

int main()
{
    MyCollector collector("Whatever ", "stuff like ", 2, " or ", 3.14, "\n");
    std::cout << collector.str();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My idea is to print each argument on the screen. If I modify the way you have suggested, it wont serve my purpose. Besides, the code, core dumps. In my definition of `init()`, the second argument being a variadic one, can be of zero length also right? Then the way I have written, should accept init(char*) right? I dont see the flaw in my argument :)

Comment: `Mystrcat<char*, char*>` will not have an `init(char*)` defined. The template parameter `P` will unpack to `char*`, which is where `init(char*, char*)` comes from.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. But I do not want to print it straight away. I need a char * which is the concatenation of all my arguments so that it can be passed as an argument to my exception function....

Comment: Updated the code again. If this isn't *exactly* what you want, you can probably modify it to do what you want.